# importing source code of mysql Jdbc driver into eclipse workspace

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have downloaded latest mysql J driver in compressed format. After unzipping file, it has jar file and its source code(src/...). How to import this code into eclipse so that i can easily debugging source code in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

**This gives you read only access for tracing program flow:**

Import the JAR the way you normally would.

In your eclipse "build path" configuration, select the jar in question, and edit the source attachment property:

[image]

**This gives you full read-write access, as if you are doing modifications to the code**

Unzip the sources into a directory.  Create a new project in eclipse.  Move the project sources into the new `src` folder that were just created in your project.

Don't forget to refresh your project (right click on the project, choose refresh.  Or, press F5)